# thunderbird smtp does send emails

Tags: thunderbird

Am having problems sending mail from my Thunderbird. I configure the SMTP server to smtp.gmail.com,and smtp.google.com still get error message saying

```
Sending of message failed.
The message could not be sent because connecting to SMTP server smtp.googlemail.com failed. 
The server may be unavailable or is refusing SMTP connections. 
Please verify that your SMTP server settings are correct and try again, or contact the server administrator.
```

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: Follow the automated prompts to set up your account it it will configure the server to the correct address which is smtp.googlemail.com, using SSL/TLS on port 465.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try and do the manual configuration,  just input your name, email and password. Mozilla maintains its own ISP and email service provider database which Thunderbird automatically checks.